# Important topics to cover in an intro course to algebraic number theory?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, advice

I am currently doing an independent study in algebraic number theory using Stewart and Tall's *Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem* textbook. I have covered the material for the course (list below). However, I have 2 weeks of course left and I was wondering if I could get suggestions of a topic which is important to see in an introduction course to ANT which is not covered in this course.

List of topics covered:

1) field extensions, minimum polynomial, algebraic numbers, conjugates, discriminants, Gaussian integers, algebraic integers, integral basis.

2) examples: quadratic and cyclotomic fields.

3) norm of an algebraic number.

4) existence of factorisation

5) factorisation in $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) $

6) ideals, $ \mathbb{Z} $-basis, maximal ideals, prime ideals

7) unique factorisation theorem of ideals

8) relationship between factorisation of number and of ideals

9) norm of an ideal

10) ideal classes

11) Minkowski convex body theorem

12) finiteness of class number

13) computations of class number

Answer (score 6):

Looks good to me! I wouldn't complain if anyone told me that that list was all they learned in an algebraic number theory course. But since you have some time, a very important technique that's not yet on your list, if you wish to continue in number theory, is completion. The $p$-adics are interesting in and of themselves, and also make lots of computations much easier (e.g. in the theory of cyclotomic fields -- which might be another nice thing to think about if you have just two weeks time).

Comment: I can't upvote this answer enough.

Comment: Thanks. Where could I learn about $p$-adics? Also, I am not familiar with completion (unless you are referring to complete metric spaces), could you suggest some readings for that also?

Comment: I would like to, I hope I am not cutting too much into Hunter's space here, highly recommend this book: http://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Structure-Algebras-Advanced-Universitext/dp/0387724877/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y

Comment: Thanks Alex. Got the book from the library and I am currently reading that part.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three nice and important topics which I would recommend:

1. The Dirichlet unit theorem
2. The Dedekind $L$-function and the class number formula
3. The modern proof of quadratic reciprocity (using the arithmetic of cyclotomic fields)